# C++ can't delete the second dimension of a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, delete-row

I am trying to make an array of pointers and each pointer to be an array of only 1 integer.
Then i want to print this integer and after i print it, i want to delete this pointer so that
it can not be printed again.
The problem is that this command "delete[] id_number[i];" seems not to work.

```
The code:


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int** id_number= new int* [12];
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        id_number[i] = new int[1];
        id_number[i][0] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        cout << "id_number ["<< i << "] [0] = "<< id_number[i][0] << endl;

        delete[] id_number[i];        //Trying to delete each pointer after printing the 
                                        //integer         
    }

    cout << endl << "After the end of loop" << endl;
    cout << "id_number [" << 5 << "] [0] = " << id_number[5][0] << endl;

    return 0;


The outcome:


id_number [0] [0] = 0
id_number [1] [0] = 1
id_number [2] [0] = 2
id_number [3] [0] = 3
id_number [4] [0] = 4
id_number [5] [0] = 5
id_number [6] [0] = 6
id_number [7] [0] = 7
id_number [8] [0] = 8
id_number [9] [0] = 9
id_number [10] [0] = 10
id_number [11] [0] = 11

After the end of loop
id_number [5] [0] = 5     // why does this print work? didn't i delete the pointer "id_number 
                            // [5]" inside the loop??
```

Comment: Any reason for your manual memory managment? You could use std::vector<std::array<int,12>> instead. Doing a new int[1] is just plain unecessary use of new /delete. Check this https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines for anything regarding new/delete and pointers.

Comment: Your program has simply undefined behavior, caused by accessing an already deleted address. It's your job to do the bookkeeping correctly, or as you're already use c++ use an appropriate container like `std::vector<T>`.

Comment: `delete[] id_number[i];` - that isn't trying to delete; it absolutely *is* deleting the referenced row. Your confusion seems to stem later from the post-apocalyptic dereference that you're doing illegally, and invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in the process, seems to still show the data you deleted earlier. The print "works" because *undefined behavior* is just that; *undefined*. Therefore, it may *appear* to work (which is frankly the worst thing that can happen, as it builds a false sense of correctness).

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the entries with

```
delete[] id_number[i]
```

set the pointer you just deleted to a nullptr like this

```
delete[] id_number[i]; id_number[i] = nullptr;
```

After deleting the alle the pointer in the arry you still have your array which occupies recources. therefore it also has to deleted

```
delete[] id_number; id_number = nullptr;
```

This should free all the resources correctly.
If you then as mentioned by WhozCraig try to acces deleted resources illegaly, undefiend behvoir will occure and my look like it does would it should which is again as mentioned by WhozCraig just undefiend behavoir.